# I am having trouble with my output

Tags: sql

I am using new version of `MySQL`. I have been trying a few exercises and I am getting this output:

> Time Action      Message Duration / Fetch 3  10:54:18    select * from
>   orgchart  LIMIT 0, 1000   1   287 row(s) returned 0.000 sec / 0.000 sec

When I close and run script, I get the output with more rows. How can I fix it? I mean, I always would like to get output with eight rows for this case. Thank you for your help.

Code:

```
create table orgchart (name text, team text, salary int, sickleave int, anuallleave int);
insert into orgchart values ('Adamovsky','Vyskum', '34000.00',34,'12');
insert into orgchart values ('Vrba','Marketing','31000.00',40,'9');
insert into orgchart values ('Sykora','Marketing','36000.00',2019);
insert into orgchart values ('Matyas','Uctovnictvo','40000.00',30,27);
insert into orgchart values ('Struhal','Vyskum','45000.00',20,17);
insert into orgchart values ('Rozehnal','Marketing','42000.00',25,18);
insert into orgchart values ('Fiala','Uctovnictvo','35000.00',22,14);
insert into orgchart values ('Preslicka','PR','375000.00',24,24);
select * from orgchart;
```

Comment: What is  the exercise? Where did the above come from?

Comment: Something missing in your code... cut-and-paste error?

Comment: Hello, what did you think? I am getting table with 287 rows not with eight rows in sql workbench. The table should be ended with Preslicka,PR... and I am sure that code is right. I did it according the book. I am getting this talble:  Adamovsky Vyskum 34000 34 12
Vrba Marketing 31000 40 9
Sykora Marketing 36000 20 19
Matyas Uctovnictvo 40000 30 27
Struhal Vyskum 45000 20 17
Rozehnal Marketing 42000 25 18
Fiala Uctovnictvo 35000 22 14
Preslicka PR 375000 24 24
Adamovsky Vyskum 34000 34 12
Vrba Marketing 31000 40 9
Sykora Marketing 36000 20 19
Matyas Uctovnictvo 40000 30 27, etc...

Comment: You need to delete rows from table `orgchart` after script running or you can just drop table.

Comment: :-)Thank you for your help. It is impossible do delete rows from table and I do not want do it. I want to get  a final table with eight rows. I closed workbench and run script again and I am getting more than 287 rows right now. I woul like to avoid it.

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried using "limit"?

```
select * from orgchart limit 8;
```

Comment: I have tried  using "limit" and you have right, it is working but I no noticed in literature that I have to do it. Does it mean  I always have to write limit 8 or anything else?

Comment: `Limit ` simply pics the defined amount of rows from the whole selected chunk of data. It really depends oh how you are querying the database. In your question, the script code and the table schema is not mentioned. Therefore, it is difficult to see what you want to achieve through the whole process. If you have duplicate entries, you might try using {DISTINCT} . It will select  only unique entries of the data.

If this information helped you, kindly accept this answer as the answer to your question.

Comment: OK. Thank you. It helped to me.

Comment: I am glad that I was able to help. Please accept this answer as the answer to your question. It will help me.

Comment: OK. I have taken another example.   select team ,count(team) from orgchart  where sickleave >= 30 group by(team);   The result: Marketing 35
Uctovnictvo 46
Vyskum 38                                                                                             I would like to achieve, how many people  have 30 or more sick days in team. The result should by three times one but I am getting no sense (35,36,38).

Comment: try this: select team, count(team) from orgchart where sickleave >=30 group by team;

It is working for me.

Comment: I would like to put the screenshot but I am not able to send it due to some rules at the moment. I am getting 35,46, 38 instead of 1,1,1. Your code is same  like me except of parenhteses.

Comment: I tried it in sqlfiddle. It worked fine. Check if there is something else that is wrong.

Comment: Thank you for your tip. I know that I can use   sql online. I have been using this one http://www.tutorialspoint.com/execute_sql_online.php  and I am getting a proper result right now.  I have no idea what is wrong with a new versoin of My SQL.